# MySQL Query 2 Tables Join Column beside

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have 2 tables, called `tb_compulsory_savings` and `tb_time_deposits`

for `tb_compulsory_savings`

```
form_no | badge_id | compulsory_savings | transaction_date
1       | 090802   | 50000              | 2016-05-20 13:10:11
2       | 090801   | 50000              | 2016-05-20 13:15:15
```

for `tb_time_deposits`

```
form_no | badge_id | time_deposits | transaction_date    | period   | status
1       | 090802   | 100000        | 2016-05-20 13:20:44 | May-2016 | closed
```

Now I want to query that 2 table to be like this:

```
badge_id | compulsory_savings | time_deposits
090802   | 50000              | 100000
090801   | 50000              | null
```

So, if `badge_id: 090801` is not existed in `tb_time_deposits`, it will display null.

I have tried LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, UNION but still the display is not as I want.

Comment: Try left join again. Show us your best effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for a `left join`:

```
SELECT    cs.badge_id, cs.compulsary_savings, td.time_deposits
FROM      tb_compulsory_savings cs
LEFT JOIN tb_time_deposits td ON cs.badge_id = td.badge_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query might work :

```
SELECT badge_id,compulsory_savings,time_deposit FROM
        tb_compulsory_savings LEFT JOIN tb_time_deposits ON 
          tb_compulsory_savings.badge_id=tb_time_deposits.badge_id;
```